# Can my nephew from Mauritius come and study in France?

Tags: france, student-visa

My nephew is 15 and will finish his current cycle of studies in September. He would like to continue his studies here in France and we are willing to host him.
Online I could only find informations about older applicants (18+). What kind of visa would he need to get his BAC here?

Comment: https://france-visas.gouv.fr/en/web/france-visas/welcome-page

Comment: Short version : is there a long term visa for a Mauritian minor who wants to study in France ? Yes. I have no idea whether it is easy to obtain.

Answer (score 1):

He can apply for a long stay visa as a minor student in secondary or higher education.

The supporting documents to be provided include:

A travel document, issued less than 10 years ago, containing at least two blank pages, with a period of validity at least three months longer than the expiry date of the visa requested.

Authorization to settle in France signed by the holder(s) of parental authority in the forms required under local law, along with a copy of his/her/their identity document (if the minor is not travelling with his/her parents or guardian).

Birth certificate or copy of family book.

Where appropriate, proof of parental authority.

Commitment to present proof of compulsory vaccinations at the educational institution in France.

If not holder of a scholarship, proof of study (transcripts and registration or pre-registration).

Parental authorization or legal minor representative, signed by the person(s) with parental authority, authorizing the host family in France (where appropriate, boarding school) to receive the child, and a photocopy of signatory(s) identity document.

Supporting letter of the parents or legal representative, explaining the reasons for the request.

If holder of a scholarship, certificate proving payment of a government scholarship and the specific amount awarded.

Proof of financial support and copy of an identity document of the sponsor who must provide proof of adequate, reliable and regular income (bank statement), as well as a copy of their ID document.

Accommodation: If internal, certificate from the director of the establishment and a copy of a proof of his identity, promise from a host family during periods when the boarding school is closed. If external, promise from a host family, copy of a proof of identity of the host, information on the nature of the accommodation.

Proof of health insurance and civil liability.

Source: https://france-visas.gouv.fr/en/web/france-visas/welcome-page